# Counter value is not incrementing while replacing in Junit request

Tags: junit, jmeter

I have created a counter (userCount) in my test plan and I want to pass that incremented counter value in Junit sampler "Constructor String Label" for each thread user like "${userid}${userCount}@user.com but here the ${userCount} is not replacing with incremented value, its always replacing with Starting value in all thread users @Dmitri T .[Please refer this Test Plan Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlnFR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) instead, it seems to be working fine. See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test/) article for more details on it if needed.

[image]

If you really have to use the Counter config element you will need to raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) and wait for the fix.

Comment: thanks for reply, I had tried __counter() function , but it seems its value always start with 1, but in my case my starting value needs to be 500 and then it has to be incremented like 501 , 502 etc for each thread user. @Dmitri T